# how to config react server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I would like dynamic meta page and share link on facebook or twitter

I have created node.js to change the meta index-page
but cache until refresh page or click to change page and call node.js change meta page

Answer (score 0):

You better use a config of that kind https://github.com/tomtom94/react-easy-ssr